# React Javascript setInterval arrow function vs function reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a difference between passing an arrow function vs passing a function reference in setInterval?

`setInterval(callbackRef.current, 5000)`

and

`setInterval(() => callbackRef.current(), 5000)`?

Why is it that the only second option works in my code? The first option prints out an old value in the callback function.

Context:

```
const MyPage = (callback, delay): void => {
  const savedCallbackRef = useRef(callback)

  useEffect((): void => {
    savedCallbackRef.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay != null) {
      const id = setInterval(savedCallbackRef.current, delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
   
  }, [delay])
}
```

UPDATED EXAMPLE:

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay): void => {
  const savedCallbackRef = useRef(callback)

  useEffect((): void => {
    savedCallbackRef.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay != null) {
      const id = setInterval(savedCallbackRef.current, delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
   
  }, [delay])
}
```

```
const My App = ({ loading }) => {
  useInterval(() => {
     if (!loading) {
        // do something
     }
  }, 500)
}
```

Comment: [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). The first one will keep a reference to the function currently stored in `callbackRef.current` while the second will have a closure that has a reference to the value currently stored in `callbackRef` which then allows you to keep getting the new values as they are assigned to `callbackRef.current`

Comment: @JacobSmit well also the first version breaks the relationship between the `callbackRef` object and the `.current()` method. Inside `.current()` in that version, the value of `this` will be incorrect (probably).

Comment: I assume if he is using arrow functions everywhere in the snippet, he will be using arrow functions everywhere else  too, which means the closure it has created (where ever it was created) should have captured whatever `this` was.

Comment: Once you change `savedCallbackRef.current` to point to the new function (that has access to the new scope with the new state values), the the function that `setInterval` is executing doesn't change (in your 1st example), as when it ran it was told to execute the `savedCallbackRef.current` callback. With the arrow function, the `setInterval()` still executes the same anonymous arrow funciton, but from that it is also able to execute the new function reference.

Comment: @NickParsons answer is correct. This has nothing to do with closures. In the first snippet, `setInterval` is invoking the function via direct reference, meaning that `setInterval` doesn't know anything about the `savedCallbackRef` object. As a matter of fact, the same function could be attached to 100 other objects. However, in the second snippet the function is invoked through the `savedCallbackRef` object which basically executes whatever function is currently attached to it.